# Sbt Package Command Do Not Copy Resources

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using sbt for a simple, small GUI projects that load icons from `src/main/scala/resources`. At first, everything works fine and I can `compile`. `package`, and `run`. The generated jar and class files all have the resource folder in it. Then I do the `clean` command. I re-run the `compile` and `package`, and suddently the application crashes. I check the generated jars and classes, and found out that the `resources` folder are not copied this time.

Running the application now gives me the `NullPointerException` pointing to the line where I load the resource (icon).

I didn't change the sbt build files or anything in the project. Just run `clean` and re-run `compile` and `package`. I don't know where to start looking for the problem. Where should I start looking? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT (the minimal example)**

The project is a standard Scala template from typesafe's g8 (https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-sbt.g8). Here's my `Build.Scala`:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object ObdscanScalaBuild extends Build {
  val scalaVer = "2.9.2"

  lazy val obdscanScala = Project(
    id = "obdscan-scala",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
      name := "project name",
      organization := "thesis.bert",
      version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
      scalaVersion := scalaVer,
      // add other settings here

      // resolvers

      // dependencies
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq (
        "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % scalaVer,
        "org.rxtx" % "rxtx" % "2.1.7"
      )
    )
  )
}
```

It builds the code fine previously. Here's the project code directory structure:

[image]

It works fine and output this directory inside the jar at first:

[image]

And suddently, when I do a `clean` and `compile` command via the sbt console, it didn't copy the resource directory in the jar or in the class directory (inside target) anymore. I can't do anything to get the resource directory copied to target now, except by restoring previous version and compile it one more time. I restore the previous version via Windows' history backup.

Is it clear enough? Anything I need to add?

**EDIT:**

After moving the files to `src/main/resources`, the compiled files now contains the resources. But now, I can't run it in eclipse. Here's my code:

```
object ControlPanelContent {
  val IconPath = "/icons/"
  val DefaultIcon = getClass.getResource(getIconPath("icon"))

  def getImage(name: String) = {
    getClass.getResource(getIconPath(name))
  }

  def getIconPath(name: String) = {
    IconPath + name + ".png"
  }
}

case class ControlPanelContent(title: String, iconName: String) extends FlowPanel {
  name = title
  val icon: ImageIcon = createIcon(iconName, 64)

  val pageTitle = new Label(title)

  protected def createIcon(name: String, size: Int): ImageIcon = {
    val path: Option[URL] = Option(ControlPanelContent.getImage(name))

    val img: java.awt.Image = path match {
      case Some(exists) => new ImageIcon(exists).getImage
      case _            => new ImageIcon(ControlPanelContent.DefaultIcon).getImage
    }
    val resizedImg = img.getScaledInstance(size, size, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)
    new ImageIcon(resizedImg)
  }
}
```

The TLDR version is this, I guess:

```
getClass.getResource("/icons/icon.png")
```

which works if I call from `sbt console` command. Here's the result when I call the code from `sbt console`:

```
scala> getClass.getResource("/icons/icon.png")
res0: java.net.URL = file:/project/path/target/scala-2.9.2/classes/icons/icon.png
```

which when runned gives the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at thesis.bert.gui.ControlPanelContent.createIcon(ControlPanel.scala:54)
    at thesis.bert.gui.ControlPanelContent.<init>(ControlPanel.scala:33)
    at thesis.bert.gui.controls.DTC$.<init>(Diagnostics.scala:283)
    at thesis.bert.gui.controls.DTC$.<clinit>(Diagnostics.scala)
    ... 60 more
```

**EDIT 2:** It works now. I just deleted the project from eclipse, re-run `sbt eclipse` and it magically works. Not sure why (maybe caching?).

Comment: Did you add a global SBT plugin?

Comment: Nope. I did use a global SBT plugin (sbteclipse), but I didn't add it after doing `clean`. I add it on the beginning of the project...

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that shows the observed behavior, please?

Comment: Ok, I'll update the post ASAP.

Comment: @Schleichardt: I've added more description, is it good enough?

Comment: Yes, your description is now very good. Please rename your Build.Scala to Build.scala (lower case S) because otherwise it is ignored on Linux systems. Did I get it right: You start your application, run the packe command while the app is running? And after that the currently running app is broken?

Comment: @Schleichardt: sorry for the late reply. I've changed the case for Build.scala, and I tried both running the package command while the app is running and not running. Both gives me the same result: didn't copy the resource directory. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SBT convention for resources is to put them in `src/main/resources/`, not `src/main/scala/resources/`. Try moving your `resources` folder up one level. Its content should then be included, meaning that you will get `icons` and `indicator` folders inside the generated jar file (directly at the root level, not inside a `resources` folder).

If you put the resources in scala, I think it copies only the files that are compiled (i.e. `.class` files resulting from scala compilation).

If it doesn't solve your problem, can you post the lines of code you use to load the resource?

Comment: I moved the files to `src/main/resources` and it indeed copies the result into jar. But now eclipse can't run the application anymore. How should I investigate the problem? Thanks.

Comment: it works now. Just re-run `sbt eclipse`, re-import the project and somehow everything works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey, sorry that I don't know I need to add the bounty manually. Just added it now :D